# Why is the execution in this VBA code not moving to the Error Handling section

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I am trying to convert a large number of xls files to xlsx.  I found some code [here](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/4/23/loop-through-all-excel-files-in-a-given-folder) that I modified to `SaveAs` with a new format. However, some fraction of my files are corrupt and they cannot be opened. I would like to simply skip those files and so I added the lines indicated in the comments (prefaced with the word `ADDED`.

Every time I run the code I still end up with a run-time error with a message that the file cannot be opened (1004 *Method Open of Object Workbooks failed*).  I use the debug button and the `Set wb~` statement is highlighted. I have tried many variations of the use of colons (I have very little experience in VBA).

Let me be clear - I have the same result whether or not there is a colon after the `NextFile`.

```vb
'Some code to pick the directory to work on and handle the case of no directory selected deleted for brevity

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
myExtension = "*.xls"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
    'ADDED next line for error handling
    On Error GoTo NextFile:
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)

    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
    DoEvents 
    'Save Workbook as XLSX file and close
    saveFileName = Replace(myFile, ".xls", ".xlsx")
    wb.SaveAs Filename:=myPath & saveFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    wb.Close   
    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
    DoEvents

    'Get next file name
    'ADDED next line for error handling
TryAgain:
    myFile = Dir
Loop

'removed some line that handle the end of the macro not needed for problem
'ADDED next line for error handling
Exit Sub
'ADDED next 2 lines for error handling    
NextFile:
    GoTo TryAgain
End Sub
```

Now this gets even more interesting. I have over 3,000 files in my initial test folder. The file that is causing the error (repeatedly) is the 121st file in sequence. Because I wanted to work on this without having to wait for three minutes (amount of time it was taking to get to the required file) I moved 20 files to a new directory - the loop completed work on all files, it did not create an XLSX version of the problem file. I then tried again on my large directory and had the same problem again. I am going to try to add new files 10 at a time to see what happens.

Comment: You're supposed to return from an error handler with `Resume`, not `Goto`.

Comment: You are saving the files into the same folder which you are enumerating, which may or may not jeopardize the enumeration. On top of that, the `"*.xls"` filter, even without the trailing `*` that you have, might [find both `.xls` and `.xlsx`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140313-00/?p=1513), which means your loop might never end as you will keep processing already processed files all over again.

Comment: Yep thanks I did not catch that - I am assuming that the reason I did not go into an infinite loop was because I think DIR runs once, when the files are all xls files.  Thanks for catching that

Comment: It is unlikely that `Dir` is implemented in a way that enumerates all files on the first call to `Dir`. That would make the first call *very* slow on large folders, which it is not. The underlying Windows mechanism for enumerating files is `FindFirstFile`/`FindNextFile`, and it [has that problem](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160210-00/?p=93011).

Comment: Make sure you have not set "Break on all errors" in your VBA options *Tools>Options>General tab > Error Trapping*

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ErrorHandling.htm  - "Do **not** use the `Goto` statement to direct code execution out of an error handling block.  Doing so will cause strange problems with the error handlers."

Comment: FYI a side effect of the error you are making (using GoTo instead of Resume) is that the loop will probably fail as you describe when it finds the _second_ bad file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As GSerg said, changing `GoTo TryAgain` to `Resume TryAgain` should fix it.

That said, a more intuitive layout might be

```
Do While myFile <> ""
    Set wb = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not wb Is Nothing Then
        'Save Workbook as XLSX file and close
        saveFileName = Replace(myFile, ".xls", ".xlsx")
        wb.SaveAs Filename:=myPath & saveFileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        wb.Close   
    End If
    myFile = Dir
Loop
```

Also, you are `Dir`'ing for `*.xls*` and saving into the same directory as you are processing. This will probably return the newly created `.xlsx` files.  I'd suggest changing to `myExtension = "*.xls"` and saving to a different folder.

Comment: Thanks I have upvoted but need some more testing to confirm as answer - still not working but I think I need a clean slate to confirm it is me and not your solution.  I will continue beating my head against this tomorrow.

Comment: Interesting - only when I set a different destination directory would this work seamlessly but it did.  I have to observe that the documentation for VBA is weak. Thanks for the help